# is it right way to set alarm at every 30 seconds ???

Tags: android

I need to start alarm at every 30 seconds, I need it to be activated without running the app. But whether the app runs or not the AlarmReceiver do not get called. Any suggestions?
start method is in MainActivity.java class

```
 public void start() {
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pintent);
    Log.d("alarm","alarm set for alarm receiver");
}
```

My Receiver file

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   // Toast.makeText(context,"Alarm Receiver ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d("Alarm","Alarm receive");

}
```

}

Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"

    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".GetLocationService"/>
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true"/>
</application>
```

here i am able to set alarm, but i didn't receive alarm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this page there is a finished example of what you need:

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/10/use-broadcast-receiver-background-services-android/

Apparently you have to change the line:

```
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

To

```
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Change your start method to this:

```
public void start() {
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    int interval = 30 * 1000; // 30 seconds of interval.
    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Let me know if works.

Comment: getting these warning message Unable to start service Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.example.bipin.getlocationdetails/.AlarmReceiver (has extras) } U=0: not found'

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue recently. The problem was with my custom Parcelable object, using primitives instead worked fine. This answer helped me: [Sending Extras to onReceive only retrieves ALARM_COUNT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48629118/sending-extras-to-onreceive-only-retrieves-alarm-count)