# Sending Extras to onReceive only retrieves ALARM_COUNT

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I made a custom view that sets an alarm with AlarmManager. I want to restore this view later so I'm trying to send the BroadcastReceiver several extras. The onReceive fails to retrieve anything but the ALARM_COUNT extra though.

I've looked for a while and count find a solution. I've tried PendingIntent.FLAG.UPDATE.CURRENT multiple flags with the intent itself but nothing works.

Is there a better way to restore a views state from a BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: Please post the code you are using to add the extras. Are you using custom objects (classes) in the extras, or just primitives and `String`s?

Comment: Just found the issue. It was with a custom class. It was implementing Parcelable but maybe the implementation was wrong.

Comment: Any idea why that would affect the rest of the extras though?

Comment: Of course. The extras are all serialized into a byte stream in the Intent. If your Parcelable implementations are not exactly correct,  the entire deserialization fails which means you get no extras.

Comment: Ah I see. As far as trying to save the state of an activity, are using intents a decent way to go about it if I'm using a notification to "restore" the activity?

Comment: Depends on how much data you want to "persist". You can also use SharedPreferences or an SQLite database.

Comment: I began storing it as sqlite. Really appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: Please answer your own question and accept your answer. That will help others who have a similar problem and remove the question from the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"extras are all serialized into a byte stream in the Intent." I was improperly adding a custom object/class which caused the entire deserialization to fail.